# Kelly Criterion with Taylor Approximation for Multiple Events

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion, expected-value, gambling

I am trying to understand how to approximate the kelly criterion when I have multiple winning events.

The Taylor approximation says that $\log(1+fr) = fr + \frac{(fr)^2}{2}$

If I have 3 winning events, wherein one I have $1/216$ chances to win $30$ times my bet, then $15/216$ to win $2$ times my bet, and $75/216$ to win my bet back, and $125/216$ to lose my bet.

Using the Taylor approximation, would this become:

$E(\log(1+fr)) = f30 + \frac{(f30)^2}{2} + f2 + \frac{(f2)^2}{2} + f + \frac{(f)^2}{2}$

$E'= 33+905f = 0 $

$f = -33/905 = -0.036$

This cant be the case since f must be positive.

Comment: Taylor gives $\ln(1+x)\approx x-\frac{x^2}{2}$ for $x\approx 0$. Seems to be a simple sign error.

Comment: Additionally : Are you sure that we can apply this formula also for a sum ? I do not know the Kelly criterion, hence I cannot judge.

Answer (score 1):

Let:

$ p_1, p_2, ... , p_n $  the probabilities of the events $ e_1,e_2, ...,  e_n $

$ r_1, r_2, ..., r_n $  the returns of events $ e_1,e_2, ...,  e_n $

$ e_1,e_2, ... e_n $  events are mutually exclusive

$ p_1 + p_2 + ... + p_n = 1 $

$ p_1r_1  + p_2r_2 + ...  + p_nr_n  > 0 $   (positive expected value)

Then:

$ G(f)= p_1\log(1 + fr_1)  + p_2\log(1 + fr_2)  + ... + p_n\log(1 + fr_n)  $

with $ G(f) $ denoting logarithmic wealth growth.

as it was given that $ \log(1+x)\approx x-\frac{x^2}{2} $ then

$ G(f) \approx p_1r_1f - \frac{1}{2}{p_1r^2_1f^2} +   p_2r_2f - \frac{1}{2}{p_2r^2_2f^2} + ... + p_nr_nf - \frac{1}{2}{p_nr^2_nf^2} $

To find the value of $ f $ for which the growth rate is maximized, denoted as $ f^* $, we differentiate the above expression and set this equal to zero.

$ p_1r_1 - p_1r^2_1f  +  p_2r_2 - p_2r^2_2f  + ... + p_nr_n - p_nr^2_nf = 0  $

$ \Rightarrow $

$ p_1r_1 +  p_2r_2 + ... +p_nr_n  = p_1r^2_1f +  p_2r^2_2f + ... + p_nr^2_nf $

$ \Rightarrow $

$ f.(p_1r^2_1 + p_2r^2_2 + ... + p_nr^2_n) = p_1r_1 + p_2r_2 + ... + p_nr_n $

$ \Rightarrow $

$ f^* \approx \frac{p_1r_1 + p_2r_2 + ... + p_nr_n}{p_1r^2_1 + p_2r^2_2 + ... + p_nr^2_n } $

For the specific case of the question raised, it is not possible to calculate Kelly, as the expected value is negative. But let's assume a similar situation where:

$ p_1=\frac{1}{216} $ ,  $ r_1=30 $,

$ p_2=\frac{15}{216} $ ,  $ r_2=10 $,

$ p_3=\frac{75}{216} $ ,  $ r_3=0 $,

$ p_4=\frac{125}{216} $ ,  $ r_4=-1 $

In that case we have:

$f^* \approx \frac{1/216*30 +  15/216*10  + 75/216*0  + 125/216*(-1) }{1/216*30^2 +  15/216*10^2  + 75/216*0^2  + 125/216*(-1)^2}    \approx  $ 2.18%